# How do I perform a LINQ query to a database?

Tags: c#, linq, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

Through the method OnNavigatedTo () I get the page an int and I make a LINQ query from a List, taking items from a database in which I LocalStorage.

```
    protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        SQLiteAsyncConnection mussAll = new SQLiteAsyncConnection("DatabaseMusei.db");
        var queryAll = await mussAll.Table<Musei>().ToListAsync();
        List<Musei> museiAll = new List<Musei>();
        foreach(Musei mus in queryAll)
           {
             museiAll.Add(mus);
           }
        IDmusei = (int)e.Parameter;
        Musei muss;
        muss = museiAll.Where(x => x.ID == IDmusei).FirstOrDefault();


//my code
    }
```

But as soon as I start reading read properties in the created object, I get this exception:

```
Message = "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
```

If you get on that page directly an object Museums and do:
 mus = (Museei) e.Parameters;
 then the program works. Where is the problem?

Comment: Which line does the exception refer to? Perhaps `e.Parameter` is an `App1.Musei`, not an `int`?

Comment: does `muss = museiAll.Where(x => x.ID == IDmusei).FirstOrDefault();` return an object? or does this exception occur above that line?

Comment: Do you mean, the exception is thrown when you read from "muss"? FirstOrDefault() can return null, so please check for it first.

Comment: Btw, so many things can be improved in this code. You are getting entire table of "Musei", create a copy of it and then filter just for one element. If you tackle the exception, we'll look at performance :)

Comment: The exception is not triggered when you read the last line of code, but when I try to read the properties inside. it is likely that the returned object is null? How do I do in that case?

Comment: if(muss != null) ...

Comment: I do not want to muss be null

Comment: I do not know how to reply to your comment.

Comment: how do I prevent muss be null?

Comment: @milovemilovino the combination of "!" and "=" gives "not equal to". Therefor what Piotr said is do `if( muss != null)`. In other words : If muss is not equal to null